# maven - advice on usage of multi-modules (jar, war, ...) project

Tags: java, maven, maven-module

I have the following Maven organization:

```
- ./pom.xml (top-level project, which defines the 4 modules below)
   - ./a/pom.xml (jar)
   - ./b/pom.xml (jar)
   - ./c/pom.xml (war)
   - ./d/pom.xml (war)
```

So far, I have been using Maven as following (all executed in the root):

```
1. mvn clean compile install
2. mvn tomcat7:redeploy -pl c
3. mvn tomcat7:redeploy -pl d
```

Although this works perfectly, I am not really sure if this is the preferred way. In the first step, I am installing **all** projects, but actually, only the jar projects `a` and `b` should be installed. There is no need to install the `c` and `d` projects.

Although it doesn't hurt installing `c` and `d`, is there a better usage of Maven to avoid this? I can always manually install `a` and `b`, but this ofcourse conterfeits the benefits of modules (auto-detection of dependency order, to name one benefit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile` and `install` are both part of the default lifecycle, so there's no need to call `compile`. And you don't need to `install` files in case dependencies are part of the reactor (i.e. all the maven projects being built). Instead `package` is good enough, although I prefer `verify` in case there are integration-tests.
You could probably do this as well: `mvn verify tomcat7:redeploy -pl c -am`, where `-am` triggers projects of the multimodule project which are required to build c.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I wanted! (I tried the same on a similar project, but there it did not succeed. I will create a new question for that.)