# maven - advice on usage of multi-modules (jar, war, …) project

Tags: java, maven, maven-module

I have the following Maven organization:

```
- ./pom.xml (top-level project, which defines the 4 modules below)
   - ./a/pom.xml (library jar)
   - ./b/pom.xml (library jar)
   - ./c/pom.xml (war)
   - ./d/pom.xml (executable jar)
```

For building and deploying the `c` project, I do:

```
mvn verify tomcat7:redeploy -pl c -am
```

For building and executing the `d` project, I do:

```
mvn verify exec:java -pl d -am
```

For `d` there is a problem. Maven reports:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli)
on project parent: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

This is indeed correct, the parent `pom.xml` has no configuration for `exec`. Only the `d` project has a configuration for `exec`.

This question is a little variation of question [maven - advice on usage of multi-modules (jar, war, ...) project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196340/maven-advice-on-usage-of-multi-modules-jar-war-project), so I decided to dedicate a separate question for it.

Why does Maven try to `exec` on the parent project?

**update**

I abstracted the same problem in following three pom files:

The parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

The a pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>a</name>
</project>
```

The b pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>b</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The command I am executing is:

```
mvn verify exec:java -pl b -am
```

This can also be found at https://github.com/jeperjaperjieper/issue-33197130.

Comment: It might help if you shared the relevant portion of your pom.xml of module d.

Comment: What version of maven? What happens if you cd into 'd' and run mvn?

Comment: @bmargulies I added extra info. If extra info required, let me know!

Comment: @hotzst I am using Maven 3.3.3.

Comment: It superficially looks like a maven bug, but, again, what happens if you cd into 'd' and just run mvn there? Most people do that rather than use -pl.

Comment: @bmargulies I tried that (`mvn clean exec:java -am`), but then Maven complains that dependencies `a` and `b` cannot be found (which are needed for `d` (and also `c`, but no problem there)). I am using a multi-module project, so I thought I always have to execute via the root.

Comment: @bmargulies I added an abstraction which shows the problem.

Comment: @bmargulies It can also be found at https://github.com/jeperjaperjieper/issue-33197130.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't cure your problem, but I can give you a recipe. You may have hit a maven issue.

You don't have to use -pl and build from the top every time.

I would expect it to work if you just run 'mvn' (no -pl) at the top; it probably doesn't take very long to build the first pieces.

If you don't want to do that, then you need to run 'mvn install' for the pieces that come first, and then you'll be able to cd into the last piece and build it.

I recommend opening up a JIRA issue for Maven on this; it *seems* as if you've exposed a problem with -pl, but the best way to find out is to post an issue with a test case and poke the Maven user mailing list.

Comment: I will report to Maven developers! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"` to run your d project.